# use one react micro-frontend in other react micro-frontend using webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-5, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I have many micro-frontends (MFE) apps in my web application but to simplify the project structure, it looks something as below,

```
MFE-Projects
|------Packages
|      |---------Auth
|      |         |------dist
|      |         |------webpack.config.js
|      |---------Common
|      |         |------dist
|      |         |------webpack.config.js
```

I want to use Common MFE in Auth MFE. For that I need to define the path at which Common MFE's `remoteEntry.js` exists. I know Common MFE's `remoteEntry.js` file exists at `D:/MFE-Projects/Packages/Common/dist/remoteEntry.js` and I try to configure webpack file as shown below,

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require("webpack").container;


module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  mode: "production",
  output: {
    filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
    publicPath: ""
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
  },
  ...
  ...
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": JSON.stringify(process.env)
    }),
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "auth",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      remotes: {

        // tried below paths but it's not working...
       
        // common: `common@D:/MFE-Projects/Packages/Common/dist/remoteEntry.js`

        common@file:///D:/MFE-Projects/Packages/Common/dist/remoteEntry.js
      },
      exposes: {
        // expose each component
        "./AuthApp": "./src/bootstrap"
      },
      ...
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

but it doesn't work. I know there is some minor mistake that I make but I'm not able to identify it.

**What am I doing wrong ?**

**FYI**: If I open browser and run `file:///D:/MFE-Projects/Packages/Common/dist/remoteEntry.js`, it opens common's remoteEntry.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Both Auth and Common packages need to have different ports allocated.
eg: If you need modules from Common MFE in Auth, You may assign port for common as 3000 and port for Auth as 3001.

And remotes should follow the example pattern below.

```
remotes: {
           common: 'common@http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js',
          }
```

Same name provided in the Remote MFE should match host. In above case, name given in the Common package's webpack.config.js should be kept before <MFE_NAME>@http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I understand it and my web app runs in production successfully. However, this approach needs common app to be in running mode continuously. I have to run common app first then verify at 3000 if commo app runs. Yes, it runs then auth can get remoteEntry.js from 3000. I don't want to do it. For local, I don't want to run common app on 3000 and then serves itself to outside world rather I want to consume common app's artifacts directly.  is that possible ?